# How does the light node handle funds on multiple addresses?

Tags: iota-network

Say I receive 1i on address with key index 0, 2i on address with index 1, and 4i on address 2:

Index 0: 1i
Index 1: 2i
Index 2: 4i

Unless there has been a snapshot, I understand that the wallet will iterate through the addresses and end up on the one with index 2. However, will it show total balance 4i or 7i? If the latter, how does it choose from which address to send? Can you choose manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wallet will show the sum of all your addresses.
It always empties addresses with lower addresses first.

Example:
Your addresses:
`A0: 1i`
`A1: 2i`
`A2: 4i`
sum = `7i`

Now you want to send 2i to another address.
This is what your addresses will look like:
`A0: 0i`
`A1: 0i`
`A2: 4i`
`A3: 1i`
sum = `7i`

The remaining 1i from `A0` and `A1` were sent to `A3`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that you wanted to spend 6i.

First, you create a 'bundle', which contains all of your addresses that contain a balance, which adds up to 6i.

Then the bundle is signed and sent to the recipient.

That recipient receives the 6i.